# In which library is "android.view.vector" declared?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I'm trying out Android Jetpack Navigation, and I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigation/com.example.android.navigation.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class vector
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class vector
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.vector" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.navigation-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.navigation-1/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

The Project build.gradle file has the following versions:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
        archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
        gradleVersion = '3.3.1'
        supportlibVersion = '1.0.0'
        navigationVersion = '1.0.0-rc02'
        dataBindingCompilerVersion = gradleVersion
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
    }
}
```

The app build.gradle file has the following dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.navigation'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$supportlibVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'    
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$supportlibVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"    
}
```

Googling did not yield any library in which "android.view.vector" is declared. Does anyone know which dependency needs to be added? Has encountered a similar issue in Android jetpack?

Thanks.

Update:

activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@drawable/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

In layout/nav_header.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navHeaderImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nav_header" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

Comment: Problem lies with the xml of MainActivity. Post xml to get the solution to this problem as error says `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`

Comment: Thanks @Surbhi. But the issue seems to be this: Didn't find class "android.view.vector" -- I think the issue seems to be on the dependencies, as the vector is used in srcCompat.

Comment: Then use android:src="@drawable/nav_header"

Answer (score 3):

Hi I think you need to use @layout/nav_header instead of the following line.

```
app:headerLayout="@drawable/nav_header"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: Thanks @Hussnain Haidar. But the issue still persists.

Comment: I have updated the post. jetifier is enabled, andoidx is enabled

Answer (score 0):

add the androidx dependency  for navigation view

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView'
```